# pi4 4gb not powering XBOX one wireless dongle

Tags: hardware, pi-4

I have a 2GB and a 4GB raspi 4 and the problem persists in both PIs

Im trying to control my robot using the xbox one controller. I want to use the dongle instead of the bluetooth to get a bit more reach.

When connected to my pc the dongle's light turns on and i can pair my controller. When i plug the dongle in the PI the light doesn't turn on and i can't pair the controller.

Could it be that the USB ports don't provide enough power to the devices? i've read a few times that that was a known issue. 
My Pis are fully updated.

Any wisdom to share? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, old Xbox drivers had a problem. You might like to try PiMyLifeUp's more updated Rpi4B Xbox tutorial: "Setting up Xbox Controllers on the Raspberry Pi - Gus, PiMyLifeUp, 2019dec15": 
https://pimylifeup.com/xbox-controllers-raspberry-pi/. BTW, PML's BlueTooth installation tutorial is also rather to date: 
"Bluetooth on the Raspberry Pi 4 - Emmetm, PiMyLifeUp, 2019dec15":
https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-bluetooth/. Cheers.

Comment: Sorry I couldnt reply before, it wouldn't allow me. Thank you for replying. Apparently is an issue with the xbox ONE drivers, xbox 360 controllers work fine.

Comment: Hi @Bernardo Belmar, No problem at all.  Nice to hear that you solved the problem. Cheers.